# JQuery and AJAX $.post() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post

I have this function that I was helped to create with one of my Uni professors. It checks the length of the password by parsing the value of the #txtNewPassword field to a 'checkpasslength.php' file, which processes the data and returns a value based on the length/contents of the data in the $.post()....The only part I don't understand is the second parameter of the $.post() function...what does the reg.password.value do exactly? I know pretty much what it does (sends the value within the form on each keypress), but what does the .reg mean?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkPassLength').load('checkpasslength.php').show();

    $('#txtNewPassword').keyup(function() {
        $.post('checkpasslength.php', {password: reg.password.value}, 
        function(result) {
            $('#checkPassLength').html(result).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what are the value for `reg`..???

Comment: where reg is coming from??

Comment: Use `console.log(reg)` inside the `keyup` method and find out yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter {password: reg.password.value} is actual password value. reg.password.value means form_name.field_name.value.